# What exceptions are there to the JavaScript property lookup rules?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, getter-setter

The following code demonstrates the "standard" rules for property lookup in JavaScript. It creates an empty object `a`, whose prototype contains a property `i`. Reading `a.i` gives the value from the prototype, but writing `a.i` creates a new property in the object itself:

```
function A() {}
A.prototype = { i: 1 }
a = new A();

console.log(a.i, a.hasOwnProperty('i'));  // 1 false
a.i = 2
console.log(a.i, a.hasOwnProperty('i'));  // 2 true
```

However, if we have a setter in the prototype, the behaviour is different. Writing `a.i` now calls the setter instead of writing directly to the object:

```
function A() {}
A.prototype = { set i(value) { this._i = value }, _i: 1 }
a = new A();

console.log(a.i, a.hasOwnProperty('i'));  // undefined false
console.log(a._i, a.hasOwnProperty('_i'));  // 1 false
a.i = 2
console.log(a.i, a.hasOwnProperty('i'));  // undefined false
console.log(a._i, a.hasOwnProperty('_i'));  // 2 true
```

The presence of a setter in the prototype has completely changed what happens on writing to `a.i`. Are there any other language features that change what happens when properties are accessed? Specifically, other than in the presence of setters, do writes always directly update an object?

Comment: The presence of a getter (or plain data property) on the prototype object also "completely changes" what happens when accessing a property. I'm not sure why you would call that an "exception".

Answer (score 0):

One exception is if your object is a Proxy, that lets you intercept **all** property calls to the object, and you get the name of the property being called. You can control lots of other behaviour too. So you can do

```
const target = {};
const proxyHandler = {
    set(target, property, value, receiver) {
         //gets called on any setter operation
    }
};
const proxy = new Proxy(original, proxyHandler );
```

Lots more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy